# DialogFragment does not float on the activity window

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I create a class extends DialogFragment class, my code is as below, my problem is the dialog hides under status bar(in the system) and the toolbar(in the activity), I refer the question here  [DialogFragment not floating, acts embeded or as another fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779870/dialogfragment-not-floating-acts-embeded-or-as-another-fragment) add  the `onCreate` function and set the style, but the dialog still only hides under toolbar, not as the tutorial said it will float on the activity window.

```
public class PasswordDialog extends DialogFragment {
......
public static PasswordDialog newInstance(PdfFragment pdfFragment) {
    Log.i(sClassTag,"newInstance in PdfFragmentPasswordDialog");
    PdfFragmentPasswordDialog passwordDialog = new PdfFragmentPasswordDialog();
    passwordDialog.mPdfFragment = pdfFragment;
    setInteractionListener(pdfFragment);
    return passwordDialog;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Pick a style based on the num.
    int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
    setStyle(style, theme);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(sClassTag,"onCreateView in PdfFragmentPasswordDialog");
    // Inflate the layout to use as dialog or embedded fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_password, container, false);
    addButtonListener();
    addEdittextListener();
    return mView;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(sClassTag,"onCreateView in onCreateDialog");
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}
void showPasswordDialog(boolean isFirstTime) {
....
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

 show(fragmentManager, "dialog");
 ...
}
```

The layout file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_img_passwordkey_48"
    android:id="@+id/key_icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/password_input_hint_message"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColorHint="@color/password_dialogUI_hint_text_color"
    android:textColor="@color/password_dialogUI_text_color"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:hint="@string/password_input_hint_message"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/dialogUI_edit_text"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textDirection="locale"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/password_error_warning_message"
    android:textColor="@color/password_dialogUI_warning_color"
    android:id="@+id/dialogUI_warning_text"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="8dp">

<Button
    android:text="@string/password_ok_button"
    android:textColor="@drawable/layout_disable_text_color"
    android:minWidth="64dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/password_dialogUI_ok_button"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_password_button_background"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

<Button
    android:text="@string/password_cancel_button"
    android:textColor="@drawable/layout_disable_text_color"
    android:minWidth="64dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/password_dialogUI_cancel_button"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/password_dialogUI_ok_button"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_password_button_background"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>
```

Comment: Can you show me "layout_password.xml" file?

Comment: Please look the modified question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Activity, try to use you use fragment.show(), instead of call your own show().

   ```
   PasswordDialog fragment = PasswordDialog();
   fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "TAG_HERE");
   ```

2. Add android:minWidth and android:minHeight to your xml.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:minWidth="1000dp"  
android:minHeight="1000dp">
```

See below:
[Full Screen DialogFragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189948/full-screen-dialogfragment-in-android)

---

Added:

3. To resize your DialogFragment, you can set values in onResume.

   ```
   public void onResume()
   {
       super.onResume();
       Window window = getDialog().getWindow();

       // You can define popup_width and popup_height
       int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_width);
       int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_height); 

       window.setLayout(width, height);
       window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // Optional
   }
   ```

See below:
[How to set DialogFragment's width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478520/how-to-set-dialogfragments-width-and-height) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17916441/850347

Comment: Thank you, I try to directly call show function it works, you save my day, but I set the dialog width as the 70% of screen width it does not work, do you know how to set it?

Comment: I added about resize FragmentDialog. If you like it, you can select this answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

here is steps to custom DialogFragment:

1.inflate custom view from xml on method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.XXX,
            container, false);
    //TODO:findViewById, etc
    return view;
}
```

2.set your dialog's width an height in onResume(),remrember in onResume()/onStart(),seems didn't work in other method

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    window.setLayout(width, height);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //TODO:
}
```